# spring security oauth2 - add custom UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have Application, which is using spring security, user data stores in database etc. 
I did extend UserDetails to be able to store more data. This additional info is being added in loadUserByUsername of my custom implementation of UserDetailsService.

Now I decided to add possibility to log via facebook/google+ and I am not able to find place where I can add my custom UserDetails to Authentication.

Here is my WebConfigurationAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final UserDetailsService boostmeUserService;
    private final OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, UserDetailsService boostmeUserService, OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.boostmeUserService = boostmeUserService;
        this.oauth2ClientContext = oauth2ClientContext;
    }

    public WebConfiguration(boolean disableDefaults, DataSource dataSource, UserDetailsService boostmeUserService, OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        super(disableDefaults);
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.boostmeUserService = boostmeUserService;
        this.oauth2ClientContext = oauth2ClientContext;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(boostmeUserService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(new BoostmeAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .loginPage("/login")
                //todo dodelat error redirect
                //.failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                //todo chci tuhle adresu jako logout?
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and().csrf()
                //todo dodelat error codes
                //.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);
    }

    /**
     * Used by remember me functionality
     */
    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return db;
    }

    /**
     * Password encryptor
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {

        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                "/connect/facebook");
        OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
        facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                facebook().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        facebookFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        facebookFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new BoostmeAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                "/connect/google");
        OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(google(), oauth2ClientContext);
        googleFilter.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
        tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), google().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
        googleFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        googleFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new BoostmeAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        filters.add(facebookFilter);
        filters.add(googleFilter);

        filter.setFilters(filters);

        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails facebook() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties facebookResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails google() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

}
```

Comment: You could create an `AuthenticationManager` with your custom `UserDetailsService` and add it to your resource server configuration. See [ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer#authenticationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer.html#authenticationManager(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager))

Comment: You could also just configure the global `AuthenticationManager`, which seems to be used by default. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/239

Comment: Not sure I understand the question well.

Comment: I just want update UserDetails on Principal Object after user logs in via facebook/google+